# Spam flag declined on post not even trying to answer a question

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, spam

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31318364/796103) for 'Spam' because it doesn't even try to answer the question.

To quote what the description for 'Spam' says:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, **[does not disclose the author's affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)**.

The page this link leads to has a bullet point **"Always solve the asker's problem."**

The post I flagged doesn't even try to do so. It is just some code copied from one of the author's projects, I assume, without any explanation of what is going on. Had the author taken the time to elaborate on how this solves OP's question, he would've noticed that it does not at all.

The code provided does what? Mess with the view hierarchy, create a toolbar and an action sheet, query the system version, query screen sizes and whatnot. These all have nothing to do with what OP asked! Just because the code also contains the class OP asked about doesn't make it an attempt to answer the question.

Considering the code has no explanation at all, is 99% off-topic, what would have been the right choice here?

Comment: I think you missed the part where it says "Exists only to promote a product or service" - what sort of product or service is that answer promoting exactly? Its own code snippet?

Comment: @BoltClock A post sure won't match all of the criteria at once, will it? What would have been the correct action here?

Comment: If it doesn't match all the criteria for spam, what makes you think it *is* spam?

Comment: @BoltClock I explained so in my post. The linked "How to not be a spammer" clearly states **always solve the asker's problem**.

Comment: What about all the posts that you flagged as NAA instead of spam - what makes them different from this one? Neither of them solve the asker's problem, which you seem to consider spam, and yet...

Comment: @BoltClock The difference is that 'please provide some code' is indeed not an answer. This one is an answer. Just one that's simply some code completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: FYI, the answer has gone. For mere mortals (under <10k rep) who can't see deleted post, this might make the discussion difficult.

Comment: @Andrew T.: They're referring to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636237/uipickerview-programatic-example/31318364#31318364 the link points to the question only.

Comment: @AndrewT. Sorry, I linked to the answer instead.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr *"This one is an answer. Just one that's simply some code completely unrelated to the question."* - that doesn't really explain **why you think it's spam**. *"It is just some code copied from one of the author's projects, I assume"* - why assume that? Even if it is, they make no attempt to promote that project either from the answer or their profile.

Answer (score 13):

Just because an answer seems completely unrelated to the question at hand doesn't make it spam.

The first part of the description says

> Exists only to promote a product or service

And *that* is what makes spam spam. I can't *tell* if this answer is promoting anything, since all it is is a code dump and nothing else.

For answers where you have no idea what they are going on about, or answers that seem to be addressing a completely different question altogether (so much so that they could have been posted under the wrong question by mistake), the appropriate option is "very low quality" or a custom flag explaining as such.

You previously applied a spam flag to a post that was something along the lines of:

> Amazing! I won some free credits, click here to download

This does indeed fit the bill of spam and is the kind of stuff the spam flag is meant for.

Answer (score 6):

> Considering the code has no explanation at all, is 99% off-topic, what
>   would have been the right choice here

Given that it: is **not** spam (it's not promoting anything); **is** an answer (just not a very good one); is neither rude nor abusive; and doesn't require any particular moderator attention, that leaves *very low quality*. Or just a downvote.